$X$ is reflexive iff $X^*$ is reflexive. Is the condition of $X$ being Banach necessary?
I saw the proof that $X$ is reflexive iff $X^*$ is reflexive here:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Banach_Space_is_Reflexive_iff_Normed_Dual_is_Reflexive
And I'm not sure if it's necessary for $X$ to be Banach. From my understanding, the Hahn-Banach theorem they used is true for non-Banach spaces as well.

Let $E$ be a subspace of $X$ and let $f_0 \in E^*$. Then there exists an extension $f \in X^*$ that agrees with $f_0$ on $E$ and their norms are equal.


$X^{**}$ is always a Banach space, so the condition is necessary.

It's not the use of Hahn-Banach, but the assertion that $J(X)$ is closed in $X^{**}$.
As $J(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X$, $X$ is complete if and only if $J(X)$ is complete. Since $X^{**}$ is automatically complete (as any space of linear maps from a normed space to a Banach space is automatically Banach), $J(X)$ will be closed in $X^{**}$ if and only if it is complete. Together, $J(X)$ is closed in $X^{**}$ if and only if $X$ is complete.
Without this assumption, there's no guarantee that such a $\Phi$ exists. It could be that $J(X)$ is dense in $X^{**}$. Then, any $\Phi \in X^{***}$ annihilating $J(X)$ must annihilate all of $X^{**}$, and so the argument breaks down.
That said, that's the only place where the argument breaks down. The only time when a normed linear space $X$ is not reflexive, but $X^*$ is, is when $J(X)$ is dense in $X^{**}$. If this is not the case, then you can simply use Hahn-Banach to build $\Phi$ from the closure of $J(X)$ in $X^{**}$, which will be a proper, closed subspace of $X^{**}$, and the rest of the argument works.
If you want, you can extend this result to normed linear spaces. You can say:

If $X$ is a normed linear space, then $X^*$ is reflexive if and only if the completion $\overline{X}$ is reflexive.

The completion of $\overline{X}$ is the unique Banach space, up to isometric isomorphism, containing $X$ as a dense subspace. The above assertion follows from the fact that $\overline{X}^*$ and $X^*$ are isometrically isomorphic; every continuous functional on $\overline{X}$ uniquely defines (through restriction), and is uniquely defined by (through extension of uniformly continuous maps) a continuous functional on $X$.
So, $X^*$ is reflexive if and only if $\overline{X}^*$ is reflexive, which is a Banach space, and hence is reflexive if and only if $\overline{X}$ is reflexive.

Excellent answer!, thank you very much :)
